# C# Wpf Custom Converter is created but not called

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've got XAML parse exception "BitmapImage UriSource must be set". While parsing, my converter is created, but Convert() method is not called. What am I doing wrong?

XAML:

```
<ImageBrush >
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
          <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=Value.Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value.Image}" CacheOption="OnLoad"></BitmapImage>
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
```

C#:

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ImageConverter()
    {
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));
        }
        catch
        {
            return new BitmapImage();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly set the `Source` or `RelativeSource` property of the Binding, you'll have to set `DataContext` property of the control that contains the ImageBrush (or one of its parent controls) to an instance of the class that has the `Value` property. You should observe a binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found kind of solution. Since I needed to use `<BitmapImage>` only for setting `CacheOption.OnLoad` so my local source file would not be locked, I've created custom `ImageConverter`:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Uri), typeof(BitmapImage))]
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ImageConverter()
    {
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if(value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            image.UriSource = value is Uri ? (Uri)value : new Uri(value.ToString());
            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            image.EndInit();
            return image;               
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Convert back function is not supported");
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Value.Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}">
</ImageBrush>
```